# Web2py Field value depends on another field - (validate while defining the model)

Tags: python, web2py, data-access-layer

Please consider the following table:

```
db.define_table('bio_data',
            Field('name', 'string'),
            Field('total_mark', 'integer', requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_INT_IN_RANGE(0, 1e100))),
            Field('marks_obtained', 'integer')
            )
```

Now the field 'marks_obtained' cannot have a value greater than the 'total_marks'.

I have tried the following

```
db.bio_data.marks_obtained.requires = IS_EMPTY_OR(
IS_INT_IN_RANGE(0, db.bio_data.total_mark))
```

But this does not work. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Field'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: find a way to get the integer value of `Field`.

Comment: Yes that is the question here, how can I get a value instead of a Field. I tried the following but still getting the error:

`Field('marks_obtained', 'integer',
                      requires=lambda row: IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_INT_IN_RANGE(0, db.bio_data(row.id).total_mark)))`

And request you to please don't downvote without understanding the complete issue or knowledge.

Comment: can you type `dir(db.bio_data.total_mark)` and see what it returns? Have you just tried `int(db.bio_data.total_mark)`

Comment: `int(db.bio_data.total_mark)` this gives the same error, as this query is `db.bio_data.total_mark` is returning a field, instead of an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using `onvalidation` callback function. Read this
[Form and validators - onvalidation](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#onvalidation)

Second solution is you need to combine '*Validators with dependencies*' and `IS_EXPR` validator. Read:

1. [Validators with dependencies](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Validators-with-dependencies)
2. [IS_EXPR](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#IS_EXPR)

Add validator in **controller** something like following, I have not tested this but you will get idea from this.

```
is_total_less = int(request.vars.marks_obtained) < int(request.vars.total_mark)

db.bio_data.marks_obtained.requires = IS_EMPTY_OR(
IS_EXPR('%s' % is_total_less,
        error_message='Marks Obtained should be smaller than Totak Marks'))
```

Make sure that `request.vars` is available.

Comment: I have been able to do it using the `onvalidation` callback. For Model level, I will try the same and update. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I've just found an elegant solution for it. First, you neet to notice that before any validation, the values of the fields travel to the model, so, in the model you can manipulate them throug the request.vars . After that everything else is easy: Just create a validator of your own, extract the values of the fields and use them as you like. An example will do better:

Let's supose you have a table with two fields:

```
    dbOBJECT.define_table("example",
                          Field("high_number",
                                "integer",
                                label= T('High number'),
                                requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(T(stringBuilder.emptyField))]),
                          Field("other_number",
                                "integer",
                                label= T('Lower number'),
                                requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(T(stringBuilder.emptyField))))
```

And you need the second number to be lower than the first. For explanation purposes let's create a custom validator. This can be done in the same db.py file

```
    class VALIDATE_NUMBERS(object):
        def __init__(self, error_message="Error, this value can't be greather than the above one"):
            self.error_message = error_message

        def __call__(self, value):
            error = None
            high_number=request.vars['high_number']

            if high_number < value:
                error = self.error_message
            return (value, error)
```

Well, the other thing to do is include this validation on the model:

```
    dbOBJECT.define_table("example",
                          Field("high_number",
                                "integer",
                                label= T('High number'),
                                requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(T(stringBuilder.emptyField))]),
                          Field("other_number",
                                "integer",
                                label= T('Lower number'),
                                requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY [(T(stringBuilder.emptyField)), VALIDATE_NUMBERS()]))
```

The magic is done!!! Enjoy...